# How to show once a repeated value in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I have this code:

```
foreach($this->authors as $autor){

    if($autor->author == $filter_autor){
        echo '<option value="'.$autor->author.'" selected="selected">'.$autor-     >author.'</option>';

    }else{
        echo '<option value="'.$autor->author.'">'.$autor->author.'</option>';
      }
};
```

The author may be repeated various times. How could I change this code to make it only print each of those which are repeated to just show once?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$var = '';
foreach($this->authors as $autor){

    if($var != $autor->author)
    {
       if($autor->author == $filter_autor){
           echo '<option value="'.$autor->author.'" selected="selected">'.$autor-     >author.'</option>';

       }else{
           echo '<option value="'.$autor->author.'">'.$autor->author.'</option>';
        }
    }
    $var = $autor->author;

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but try this:

```
foreach(array_unique($this->authors) as $autor){

    if($autor->author == $filter_autor){
        echo '<option value="'.$autor->author.'" selected="selected">'.$autor-     >author.'</option>';

    }else{
        echo '<option value="'.$autor->author.'">'.$autor->author.'</option>';
      }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to filter the array BEFORE you begin the output.

If that's not possible, for whatever reason (including personal preference), try something like this:

```
$used_authors = array();
foreach($this->authors as $autor){
  if(!isset($used_authors[$autor->author]){
    if($autor->author == $filter_autor){
        echo '<option value="'.$autor->author.'" selected="selected">'.$autor-     >author.'</option>';

    }else{
        echo '<option value="'.$autor->author.'">'.$autor->author.'</option>';
    }
    $used_authors[$autor->author] = true;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
$newarray=array_unique($this->authors);
    foreach($newarray as $autor){
    
        if($autor->author == $filter_autor){
            echo '<option value="'.$autor->author.'" selected="selected">'.$autor-     >author.'</option>';
    
        }else{
            echo '<option value="'.$autor->author.'">'.$autor->author.'</option>';
          }
    }
```

Learn about [array_unique()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
 $unieq_array=array_unique($this->authors);

        foreach($unieq_array as $autor){

            if($autor->author == $filter_autor){
                echo '<option value="'.$autor->author.'" selected="selected">'.$autor-     >author.'</option>';

            }else{
                echo '<option value="'.$autor->author.'">'.$autor->author.'</option>';
              }
        };
```